# How would I find the expected interest rate $E[1+i]$?

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose the rate of interest $i$ on an investment is $20 \%$ with probability $0.1$, $5 \%$ with probability $0.4$,$2 \%$ with probability $0.4$, and $-10 \%$ with probability $0.1$.

How would you find $E[1+i]$?

Is $E[1+i]=1+E[i]$?

If so, why is $0.1(1+0.2)+0.4(1+0.05)+0.4(1+0.02)+0.1(1-0.1) \neq 1+0.1(0.2)+0.4(0.05)+0.4(0.02)+0.1(-0.1)$?

Comment: "Is E[1+i]=1+E[i]?" Yes. Actually, E[x+y]=E[x]+E[y] for every x and y.

Comment: "If so, why is" Who says they are not equal?